# JavaFX TableView - not update after List was updated and Table refreshed

Tags: java, javafx

I have this interface:

```
//global var
static List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    TableView<Foo> tableView = new TableView<>();
    tableView.setPlaceholder(new Label("No data"));

    TableColumn<Foo, Integer> colIndex = new TableColumn<>("index");
    colIndex.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("index"));

    tableView.getColumns().add(colIndex);
    tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(list));

    Button btn = new Button("update list");
    btn.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {

        Random r = new Random();

        List<Foo> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        newList.add(new Foo(r.nextInt()));
        newList.add(new Foo(r.nextInt()));

        list.clear();
        list.addAll(newList);

        list.forEach(e1 -> System.out.println(e1.getIndex()));

        tableView.refresh();

    });

    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(btn, tableView);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vbox));
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

> Foo class

```
private int index;

public Foo(int index){
    this.index = index;
}
```

When I press on button I want to refresh table with new values from `list`

My problem is that table is not updated in interface after `tableView.refresh()`.

Why the table not update and how I can force it to update?

Comment: [`FXCollections#observableArrayList(Collection)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList(java.util.Collection)) _copies_ the given `Collection`, meaning your `list` is disconnected from the table's items list.

Comment: @Slaw ye, my bad. `observableList` solved problem. thanks!

Comment: It's a bad idea to work with the backing list anyways. Modify the `ObservableList` directly and you don't need to call `refresh`: `tableView.getItems().setAll(newList);` Also note that using `onAction` instead of `onMouseClicked` would be preferable, since this can also be triggered using the keyboard and also does not trigger when licking mouse buttons other than the primary one...